# Creating new polygon in between other polygons?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

I want to fill the missing space and create a polygon out of it. How do you do that with QGIS?

The missing space is the white part between the selected/yellow polygons.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: (1) Dissolve all > (2) Delete holes > Difference (2) - (1). P.s. Beforehand check the geometry quality with "Fix geometries", "Remove null geometries" and "Delete duplicate geometries".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS you can achieve this just activating the *Avoid Overlap* option inside the *Snapping Options*.

Activate the Snapping and open the Snapping Options:

[image]

Here, select the option *Advanced Configuration* and click, to activate, the options *Topological Editing*.

Activate (check it) the layer(s) that delimitated the empty space and, finally, check the option Avoid Overlap in the layer(s).

[image]

Now you can just draw a new polygon with its nodes inside the surrounding polygons and the system it will avoid automatically any overlap creating a new geometry that covers only the empty space.

**Addendum**

Since the Version 3.14 QGIS has a new Snapping toolbar and the Overlapping option has a dedicate icon:

[image]